# Binary Search Tree Print Nodes by Level in C++ Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Hi Everyone i know this is kind of simple question for most of the guys ,So please help me,what i am trying to achieve how can we print the nodes of a binary search tree Recursively By Level Like

```
                         5
                        / \
                       /   \
                      3     7
                     /\    /\
                    /  \  /  \
                   2    4 6   8


    Expected Print

Level o : 5
Level 1 : 3 7
Level 2   2 4 6 8
```

What will be the base case and Recursive case,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's called a level-order tree traversal. You can check the link here, it will give you the algorithm:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal/

Comment: i don't know i got 2 down voted i must have search the web first but that's ok. its a part of learning. Thank you